# How to display all the data which is groupby "Cause" from 1981 to 1992 in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've fetched the data from CSV file which contains data from 1981 to 1999 but I want to fetch the data from 1981 to 1992, but i don't know how to implement between query in a dataframe.
Here are some of my code.....
[CSV File Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwbWTt4y8kW3X2RqOUFJVUxZVTg/view?usp=sharing)

**Python Pandas Code**

```
col_names = ['Country','Cause','Deaths1','Sex','Year']
return_data=pd.read_csv("test.csv",low_memory=False,usecols=col_names);
temp_return=return_data[return_data['Country']==4184].groupby('Cause').max()
efg=temp_return.iloc[1:21]
returnCount=efg[efg.columns.difference(['Sex','Country','Year'])]
returnCount
```

The upper code fetched all years data...
help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would make a dataframe of the grouped data so we can easily slice and/or filter the data.

```
#Option 1: Filter input dataframe
    return_data=return_data.ix[return_data.year.isin(list(np.arange(1981,1993,1)))]
temp_return=pd.DataFrame(return_data[return_data['Country']==4184].groupby(['Year','Cause']).max())
```

Comment: Thanks for you help buddy but nothing happened it shows nothing,I updated the link now you can get access to this file please help me to get the right answer

Comment: ix is deprecated

Comment: Thats weird, the "return_data=return_data.ix[return_data.year.isin(list(np.arange(1981,1993,1)))]" selects all the right data for me.  I think the problem has something in the fact that you do a groupBy only with 'Cause', but you don't do a groupBy(['year','cause']) to, therefore you lose the 'year'-level in the groupBy.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the desired years like this:

```
efg = temp_return[temp_return['Year'].isin(temp_return['Year'].unique().sort_values()[:13])]
```

Comment: I want to get the result from 1981 to 1993 but in your answer where was the years mentioned?

Comment: I missed closing `]`. I figured that your years start from 1981 and that you need next 12 (total 13) years.

Comment: Please try to understand,i have to mention the years and sort_values() you used is not the object of numpy